# How to trap exit code in Bash script

Tags: bash, signals, exit-code, bash-trap

There're many exit points in my bash code. I need to do some clean up work on exit, so I used trap to add a callback for exit like this:

```
trap "mycleanup" EXIT
```

The problem is there're different exit codes, I need to do corresponding cleanup works. Can I get exit code in mycleanup?

Comment: trap 'foo' EXIT or trap 'foo' CHLD ?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I think you can use `$?` to get the exit code.

Comment: @Todd: The variables `$BASH_COMMAND` and `$BASH_LINENO` come in handy sometimes, too.

Comment: @Todd, @bmk : don't forget that *any* command executed changes the value of $?; for example,  myCmdIWantToTest ; echo $? ; myRC=$? ;  ... now myRC is the 'truth' of the echo $? cmd being invoked. If myCmdIWantToTest exited 'false', that value is lost. It is best to save $? to a separately named var that is unique. Using exitCode=$? universally, you can easily wind-up inheriting some other cmd's exitCode (or more likely from a sub-shell(script) ). Also, don't forget that it is OK test exit code as part of an if ; then ; ... fi. Like if myCmdIWantToTest ; then echo worked; else echo failed; fi

Answer (score 90):

The accepted answer is basically correct, I just want to clarify things.

The following example works well:

```
#!/bin/bash

cleanup() {
    rv=$?
    rm -rf "$tmpdir"
    exit $rv
}

tmpdir="$(mktemp)"
trap "cleanup" EXIT
# Do things...
```

But you have to be more careful if doing cleanup inline, without a function. For example this won't work:

```
trap "rv=$?; rm -rf $tmpdir; exit $rv" EXIT
```

Instead you have to escape the `$rv` and `$?` variables:

```
trap "rv=\$?; rm -rf $tmpdir; exit \$rv" EXIT
```

You might also want to escape `$tmpdir`, as it will get evaluated when the trap line gets executed and if the `tmpdir` value changes later that might not give the expected behaviour.

Edit: Use [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/) to check your bash scripts and be aware of problems like this.

Comment: or you can use single quotes:

   trap 'rv=$?; rm -rf $tmpdir; exit $rv' INT TERM EXIT

Answer (score 9):

I've found it is better to separate EXIT trap from the trap for other signals

Example trap test script...

```
umask 77
tmpfile=`tmpfile.$$`
trap 'rm -f "$tmpfile"' EXIT
trap 'exit 2' HUP INT QUIT TERM

touch $tmpfile
read -r input 

exit 10
```

The temporary file is cleaned up.
The file exit value of 10 is preserved!
Interrupts result in an exit value of 2

Basically as long as you don't use "exit" in a EXIT trap, it will exit with the original exit value preserved.

ASIDE: Note the quoting in the EXIT trap. That lets me change what file needs to be cleaned up during the scripts lifetime.  I often also include a test for the existence of the $tmpfile before trying to remove it, so I don't even need to set it at the start of the script, only before creating it.

Answer (score 6):

The following code works well. You can store the exit code and define the commands that are needed for each exit code in the trap function.

```
#!/bin/bash
trap cleanup EXIT
cleanup() {
   exit_code=$?
   if [[ ${exit_code} -eq 1 ]]; then
       # command 1
   elif [[ ${exit_code} -eq 2 ]]; then
       # command 2
   elif [[ ${exit_code} -eq 3 ]]; then
       # command 3
   fi
}
```