# Avoid yum error when a package is already installed

Tags: shell, amazon-ec2, error-handling, yum

I am using AWS Elastic Beanstalk on a Linux machine and need to install some fonts in .ebextensions:

```
container_commands:
  01_getfont: 
    command: sudo yum -y install http://somesite.com/rpm/webcore-fonts-3.0-1.noarch.rpm
```

That works well the 1st time, with the fonts installed.

The 2nd time when I deploy the EB again, it now gave me this error:

Application update failed at 2019-01-28T23:44:14Z with exit status 1 and error: container_command 01_getfont in .ebextensions/fonts.config failed.

```
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
Examining /var/tmp/yum-root-0Yx1DY/webcore-fonts-3.0-1.noarch.rpm: webcore-fonts-3.0-1.noarch
/var/tmp/yum-root-0Yx1DY/webcore-fonts-3.0-1.noarch.rpm: does not update installed package.
Error: Nothing to do.
```

How do I avoid getting that errors when that package has been installed on the same EC2 instance the 2nd time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [packages](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-packages) directive:

```
packages:
  rpm:
    webcore-fonts: http://somesite.com/rpm/webcore-fonts-3.0-1.noarch.rpm
```

This will handle not installed and already installed scenarios.

Answer (score 6):

I found out the answer to this problem later, posting it here for the benefits of others with similar issue.

I use reinstall instead:

```
sudo yum -y reinstall http://somesite.com/rpm/webcore-fonts-3.0-1.noarch.rpm
```

This will work the 1st time and all other times of deployment.

**Edit:**

The above does not work as well as reinstall will fail if package is not installed. I ended up detecting if the package has been installed, if not, install it else re-install:

```
command: sudo yum -q list installed webcore-fonts.noarch &>/dev/null && sudo yum -y reinstall http://somesite.com/rpm/webcore-fonts-3.0-1.noarch.rpm || sudo yum -y install http://somesite.com/rpm/webcore-fonts-3.0-1.noarch.rpm
```

Answer (score 2):

Yum can return a non-zero exit status for things that are not really errors, causing higher-level systems such as Elastic Beanstalk to think the script has failed.

In particular, yum sometimes says "Nothing to do" with exit status of 1 - this can mean various things but includes the case where required packages are already installed.

The way I work around this for scripts using yum is:

```
    yum -y install somepackage
    if [ $? -ne 1 ]; then   # Exit on any any error except 'nothing to do' 
      exit 0
    fi
```

A simpler way is just to ignore all errors by appending a `true` or `exit 0` command - however, this is eventually going to bite you when the Yum repo is unreachable, or Yum has out of date metadata, etc.

### Advanced tip

If you have several yum commands, or more error codes to handle, you might want to read up on the shell `trap` command, specifically on `EXIT` or `ERR` which lets you handle these cases in a single place, and potentially not exit on unwanted errors.  See [this stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5312266/how-to-trap-exit-code-in-bash-script) for more on this.

### Alternative for local installs

See [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/880398/yum-install-local-rpm-throws-error-if-up-to-date) for more, including a simple alternative when installing RPMs that you have downloaded.